# scaling spawn object randomly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my script to spawn my object.

```
public Transform topTransform;
public GameObject Platform;
public float platformDistance;
public int initialParts

private List<GameObject> spawnedPlatforms = new List<GameObject>();


public void LoadLevel(int levelNumber)
{

    float spawnPosZ = topTransform.localPosition.z;

    for (int i = 0; i < initialParts ; i++)
    {
        spawnPosZ += platformDistance;

        GameObject platform = Instantiate(Platform, transform);
        Debug.Log("Platforms spawned");
        platform.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, spawnPosZ);
        spawnedPlatforms.Add(platform);
    }
}
```

I would like to make this but with different sizes:
[image]

please help me with script to spawn this object at random scale(z-axis) at given min and max range(2, 6)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

Set the object's `transform.localScale` using `Random.Range(2f, 6f)`, and then also increase `spawnPosZ` by an amount based on that scale:

```
public Transform topTransform;
public GameObject Platform;
public float platformDistance;
public float halfBasePlatformWidth = 0.5f;
public int initialParts

private List<GameObject> spawnedPlatforms = new List<GameObject>();


public void LoadLevel(int levelNumber)
{

    float spawnPosZ = topTransform.localPosition.z;

    for (int i = 0; i < initialParts ; i++)
    {  
        float zScale = Random.Range(2f, 6f);
        float halfPlatformWidth = halfBasePlatformWidth * zScale;
        spawnPosZ += platformDistance + halfPlatformWidth;

        GameObject platform = Instantiate(Platform, transform);
        Debug.Log("Platforms spawned");
        platform.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, spawnPosZ);
        platform.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, zScale);
        spawnedPlatforms.Add(platform);

        spawnPosZ += halfPlatformWidth;
    }
}
```

You will have to change `basePlatformWidth` and `platformDistance` to make this work.

Comment: i think the problem is with spawnPosZ because when increasing in scale randomly distance between two platforms are not same sometimes they will over lap each other.  i have done few calculations i think we need to add (length(z) difference between Platform and previous Platform ) to platformDistance , so distance between two platform will be same

Comment: @GaneshKumar I saw you attached an image in the question but didn't show it. I think I understand what you mean. I remade my answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: you see distance between two platforms are different  and i still didnt understand basePlatformwidth * zScale part?  when i tried with add the value (length(z) difference between Platform and previous Platform (i mean suppose previous generated platform Z value is 4 and current platform is 5) 5-4 =1  ) to platformDistance then its working fine but how do i write that in code

Comment: @GaneshKumar Thank you, I realized you need to add half the platform width after each platform, and have changed my code. Please see it now. Note the change to `halfBasePlatformWidth`

Comment: Thank you, still same distance between two platforms are different . still i didnt understand your method

Comment: spawnPosZ += platformDistance + (here i want to add  length(z) difference between current Platform and previous Platform (i mean suppose previous generated platform Z value is 4 and current platform is 5) 5-4 =1) then it will definitely work

Comment: spawnPosZ += platformDistance + (Platform(localScale_Zvalue) - zScale); how to write this in correct manner for this loop

Comment: @GaneshKumar you need to adjust the value of  `halfBasePlatformWidth` until it works. It is based on the size of the platform, and there is not enough information in the question to tell you what that value needs to be.